# Reference request for qualitative study of implicit functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request

I would like to state clearly that I am not looking for a proof of the implicit function theorem.

When I was a student, I read a book of mathematical analysis where a chapter was devoted to the "art" of drawing functions defined by an implicit relation. More precisely, given the equation $F(x,y)=0$ with suitable assumptions on $F$, the author was able to develop several techniques to draw an accurate graph of the *unique* function $y=f(x)$ defined implicitly: domain of definition, limits, asymptotes, monotonicity, and so on.

That book was very old and written in italian, so I am looking for a textbook in english where such a "theory" can be found. Can anybody help me?